# obtener datos de una tabla pivote

Tags: php, laravel-5

estoy trabajando con laravel 5.4... tengo una consulta que quizás sea bastante sencilla de responder pero no he podido dar con la solución, tengo una tabla estado y otra llamada organizacion a estas dos las une una tabla intermedia llamada estado_organizacion la cual tiene los ids de cada tabla además de un campo llamado "nota"

[image: tabla estado_organizacion]

resulta que desde el controlador tengo lo siguiente.

```
$organizacion = Organizacion::findOrFail($id);
$detalle_organizacion = $organizacion->estados()->first()->pivot;
```

esto me devuelve solamente el primer registro de la organización que coincida con el id de la siguiente manera.

```
{organizacion_id: 21, estado_id: 1, nota: "nota de serviline limitada prospecto.", created_at: "2018-10-13 00:30:00", updated_at: "2018-10-13 00:30:00"}
```

hasta aquí todo bien, pero resulta que en la tabla pivote tengo mas de un registro por cada organización ya que cada organización va pasando por diferentes estados dejando notas de porque se ha actualizado el cambio de estado.

la pregunta es ¿como puedo obtener todos los registros de una organización?

he probado utilizando el metodo all(), pluck(), get() y no he obtenido el resultado que ando buscando.

desde ya les agradezco sus respuestas.

Answer (score 2):

Debes de usar las relaciones dentro de Eloquent, en la documentación de Laravel viene bien explicado este tema

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role')->withPivot('column1', 'column2');
```

Necesitas usar una relacion HasMany para entre tu tabla y tabla pivote

Answer (score 0):

muchas gracias por responder, lo que me indica @Victor Gonzalez ya lo tenia previamente configurado en mi modelo, de todas formas solucione mi problema con la siguiente linea de código

```
$organizacion->estados()->select('estado_id','organizacion_id','nota', 'fecha_creado', 'fecha_actualizado')->get();
```

esto me devuelve todos los registros que coincidan con el id de la organización de la siguiente manera.

> 0: {estado_id: 1, organizacion_id: 21, nota: "nota para prospecto ", fecha_creado: "2018-10-15 13:15:00", fecha_actualizado: "2018-10-15 13:15:00", …}
>   1: {estado_id: 2, organizacion_id: 21, nota: "nota para contactado", fecha_creado: "2018-10-15 13:15:00", fecha_actualizado: "2018-10-15 13:25:00", …}
>   2: {estado_id: 2, organizacion_id: 21, nota: "nota de contactado numero 2", fecha_creado: "2018-10-16 12:00:00", fecha_actualizado: "2018-10-15 12:00:00", …}

agradezco su tiempo.

Answer (score -2):

tienes que usar query builder, y hacer joins.. al momento de pasar el id de una organizacion te agrupe todos los estados,ejemplo: organizacion hace el join a la tabla pivote y luego un join a la tabla notas, luego las agrupas por el idOrganizacion y te mostrara todas las notas que tiene esa organizacion.. espero te sirve y te aclare tus dudas.